# Regex for last occurence of String between fix determinator

Tags: javascript, regex, oracle, plsql

So I am having a specific string returned in the following structure:

```
"http://www.google.com/search","XYZ","Some other Value","false","false","2017-12-13"
```

I only want to find the last occurrence of a date from the format "YYYY-MM-dd", as it could also be, that the values "false" may be returning a date.

I am not experienced in regular expressions, but the last thing I achieved was to receive `2017-12-12"*` with the following expression :

```
**((?:[^"]"*){10})$**
```

Looking for the occurrence of a date in the desired format won't help, as multiple dates might occur.

This is why I want to check for the last String between quotation marks. How will I get this date without quotation marks?

Comment: Try `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?="$)`

Answer (score 1):

> I want to check for the last String between quotation marks

Just:

```
regexp_replace(myvalue, '^.*"([^"]+)"$', '\1')
```

Regexp breakdown:

```
^          beginning of the string
.*         any sequence of 0 to N characters
"          double quote
(          beginning of the capturing group
    [^"]+      as many characters as possible other than a double quote (at least one)
)          end of the capturing group
"          double quote
$          end of string
```

The regexp matches on the entire string and replaces it with the catpured part.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c8fe6d95bd2f5d7eb4aa131409a11128)**:

```
with t as (select '"http://www.google.com/search","XYZ","Some other Value","false","false","2017-12-13"' myvalue from dual)
select regexp_replace(myvalue, '^.*"([^"]+)"$', '\1') mydate from t
```

```
| MYDATE     |
| :--------- |
| 2017-12-13 |
```

---

If needed, you can be more specific by specifying the expected date format in the capturing group:

```
regexp_replace(myvalue, '^.*"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})"$', '\1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regex to do it:

```js
/^(?:".*?",)*"(.*?)"$/
```

Alternatively, you could use `String#split()` and `String#slice()`:

```js
const output=input
  .split(',')
  .pop()
  .slice(1,-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `"false", "false", "2017-12-13"` can be any combination of three dates or three `false`s, or anywhere in between, and you're looking to find the last **date**. I would use

```regex
(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d(?!.*\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d))
```

Which will capture a date as long as it is not followed by another.

See my example here:
https://regex101.com/r/GAkpDI/1/

```
"http://www.google.com/search","XYZ","Some other Value","2018-04-09","false","<<2017-12-13>>"
"http://www.google.com/search","XYZ","Some other Value","<<2018-12-09>>","false","false"
"http://www.google.com/search","XYZ","Some other Value","false","<<2000-09-17>>","false"
"http://www.google.com/search","XYZ","Some other Value","2018-12-09","2000-09-17","<<2017-12-13>>"
```

I have put the matches inside of `<<>>`.

---

**Edit**: If you don't know the format the date will be in, then you could swap it for something that just finds numbers, dashes, and slashes:

https://regex101.com/r/GAkpDI/2/

```regex
([\d-\/]+(?!.*[\d-\/]+))
```

This will be more likely to fail, as it will find anything `[0123456789-/]`, but if your program will only ever put a date or `false` in there, it should still be viable.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple `regexp_substr` as following:

```
select regexp_substr('"http://www.google.com/search","XYZ","Some other Value","false","false","2017-12-13"',
'((\d){4}(-)(\d){2}(-)(\d){2})"$',1,1,null,1)
from dual;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=21de4ead9e7694175cb02b0251f05d8a)

Here, parameters of the `regexp_substr` are as follows:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR( string, pattern [, start_position [, nth_appearance [, match_parameter [, sub_expression ] ] ] ] )
```

Cheers!!